# Using methods of a different Project (Project References in Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

How do I use methods and interfaces of a different project that I have in the workspace(Eclipse Juno)?

Project A needs to reference Project B's methods.

I did new>other>android project from existing code and got project B into the workspace.

From here I did not know what to do. The last thing that I have done is add Project B to project A's " Project References" through properties but importing doesn't seem to work for me.

UPDATE:
Attempting to use a method from Project B.

Project 
    [2013-07-16 14:18:03 - Project A] ------------------------------

```
[2013-07-16 14:18:03 - Project A] Android Launch!

[2013-07-16 14:18:03 - Project A] adb is running normally.

[2013-07-16 14:18:03 - Project A] Performing com.package.maps.MainActivity activity launch

[2013-07-16 14:18:04 - Project A] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-07-16 14:18:04 - Project A] Project dependency found, installing: Project B
[2013-07-16 14:18:04 - Project B] Uploading Project B.apk onto device '014691470'
[2013-07-16 14:18:04 - Project B] Installing Project B.apk...
[2013-07-16 14:18:04 - Project B] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2013-07-16 14:18:04 - Project B] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2013-07-16 14:18:04 - Project B] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.andal.projectB' in a shell.
[2013-07-16 14:18:04 - Project A] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Firstly, are the methods declared public? If yes then you can use then by creating objects. You can also make them static and access the methods statically like `CLASSNAME.MEHOD(paams)`. ( Assuming you've referenced it corectly) Please do elaborate more.

Comment: you will have to make one project a library project and then reference the same in another project. does your 1st project refer to resources?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @Juned answered my question. I just did not know if I had gotten Project B into Project A(essentially). Thanks again

Comment: @benzabill uninstall and reinstall the app.

Comment: I am sorry but could you elaborate? I am making an android app and I already uninstalled that from the phone but I assume that's not the correct thing

Comment: This happens sometimes. what you see in the log. just uninstall the old one and reintall with the new apk. Why do you assume that's not the correct thing?

Comment: I think it's asking me to uninstall Project B not Project A and I don't think Project B is installed on my device

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33582/discussion-between-benzabill-and-raghunandan)

Comment: @benzabill i guess you have to make 1st project a library project and reference the same in 2nd project. Library Projects
These projects contain shareable Android source code and resources that you can reference in Android projects. This is useful when you have common code that you want to reuse. Library projects cannot be installed onto a device, however, they are pulled into the .apk file at build time. http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the required project into the `java build path` of your project. Do this in eclipse:

> Right click on your project  -> Java Build Path -> Projects (add the
>   project you want to use)

Comment: do i need to do imports or not?

Comment: @benzabill You will require the imports for the classes you want to use.

Comment: I attempted to use a variable from one of the methods and got the errors that I have updated in my post.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject/ @JunedAhsan your sugestion won't work if the 1st android project java files refers to resources files ( xml drawable resources). if the 1st project contains pure java files then you can package into jars and use the same in second project. But you cannot package resources files into jar. Edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Raghunandan and @Juned, this question has been solved.

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

As per the google docs, Project B needed to be made a library and then added through the properties of Project A.